# twitter bootstrap AND rails 3 Jumbotron masthead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed the twitter bootstrap rails gem and ran all the commands.

I have seen some basic style changes which leads me to some confidence. However with I use the following class

```
    <div class="jumbotron masthead">
      <h1>Test Heading</h1>
      <p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
   </div>
```

It does not do anything. According to the twitter bootstrap homepage and inspecting, this should work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the bootstrap gem uses the latest version of Bootstrap? I always include the CSS and JS files manually, so that I can always have the latest version. I haven't used the masthead, but it is included in the Bootstrap CSS files. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/docs.css#L58

Comment: When using the css file manually, I am assuming you install it into the assets folder. How do you then require it?

Comment: There must be something else wrong - I can get the jumbotron working by copying the css into the style sheet (in fact I copied the entire css found https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/docs.css#L58.

But things like <p class="text-left</p> does not have any effect...

Comment: Yes, I add everything to the corresponding folder inside the assets. You need to copy all the files from the bootstrap zip to the correct folder. Every `*.min.css` should go in the `app/assets/stylesheets` folder and every `*.min.js` to the `app/asssets/javascripts` folder. If you add this to your project, try removing the gem. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

The jumbotron masthead was an extra addition on the Bootstrap GitHub doc pages that isn't included in the "proper" release of Bootstrap.

There's nothing to stop you pinching the code from [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/docs.css#L58) and adding it to your Rails project yourself though!

Comment: I thought so, So I just add the code to the bootstrap_and_overides.css file directly?

Comment: You can add it wherever you like - but I'd create a file called "bootstrap_additions.css" in your /app/assets/stylesheets folder. If your application.css file has `*= require_tree .` in it then you're ready to roll, otherwise add it as a specific `*= require bootstrap_additions.css`.